# Bug in Splay tree insertion implementation

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures, tree, splay-tree

I have been trying to implement splay tree but met with no success so far.Previously I successfully implemented binary search tree and avl tree and since splay tree is a variation of binary search tree so the insertion code and rotation code is fine.The only problem I am facing is moving the node up to the root each time a node is inserted.This is my code

```
class SplayTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None
        self.size = 0

    def moveUp(self, currentNode):
        if currentNode.parent:
            if currentNode.parent.parent is not None:
                #zig zag
                if currentNode.isRightChild() and currentNode.parent.isLeftChild():
                    self.rotateLeft(currentNode.parent)
                    self.rotateRight(currentNode.parent)

                elif currentNode.isLeftChild() and currentNode.parent.isRightChild():
                    self.rotateRight(currentNode.parent)
                    self.rotateLeft(currentNode.parent)

                #zig zig
                if currentNode.isLeftChild() and currentNode.parent.isLeftChild():
                    self.rotateRight(currentNode.parent.parent)
                    self.rotateRight(currentNode.parent)

                elif currentNode.isRightChild() and currentNode.parent.isRightChild():
                    self.rotateLeft(currentNode.parent.parent)
                    self.rotateLeft(currentNode.parent)
                self.moveUp(currentNode)

            #zig
            if currentNode.isLeftChild():
                self.rotateRight(currentNode.parent)
            elif currentNode.isRightChild():
                self.rotateLeft(currentNode.parent)
            self.moveUp(currentNode)

        else:
            return

    def put(self,key,val):
        if self.root:
            self._put(key,val,self.root)
        else:
            self.root = TreeNode(key,val)
        self.size += 1

    def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):               
         if key < currentNode.key:
            if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
            else:
                currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
            self.moveUp(currentNode.leftChild)

         else:
            if currentNode.hasRightChild():
                self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
            else:
                currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
            self.moveUp(currentNode.rightChild)

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.put(key,value)

    def rotateLeft(self, rotRoot):
        newRoot = rotRoot.rightChild
        if newRoot.leftChild is not None:
            rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild
            newRoot.leftChild.parent = rotRoot
        # if subtree is at top or somewhere in between
        # make connection between node and parent
        newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
        if rotRoot.parent is None:
            self.root = newRoot
        # make connection between parent and node
        else:
            if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
                rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
            else:
                rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
        newRoot.leftChild = rotRoot
        rotRoot.parent = newRoot

    def rotateRight(self, rotRoot):
        newRoot = rotRoot.leftChild
        if newRoot.rightChild is not None:
            rotRoot.leftChild = newRoot.rightChild
            newRoot.rightChild.parent = rotRoot
        newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
        if rotRoot.parent is None:
            self.root = newRoot
        else:
            if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
                rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
            else:
                rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
        newRoot.rightChild = rotRoot
        rotRoot.parent = newRoot

    def inorder(self):
        print("INORDER")
        if self.root:
            self._inorder(self.root)
            print()
        else:
            return None

    def _inorder(self,currentNode):
        if currentNode:
            self._inorder(currentNode.leftChild)
            print(currentNode.key,end=" ")
            self._inorder(currentNode.rightChild)

class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self,key,val,left = None,right = None,parent = None):
        self.key = key
        self.payload = val
        self.leftChild = left
        self.rightChild = right
        self.parent = parent

    def hasLeftChild(self):
        return self.leftChild

    def hasRightChild(self):
        return self.rightChild

    def isLeftChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.leftChild == self

    def isRightChild(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.rightChild == self

    def isLeaf(self):
        return not (self.leftChild or self.rightChild)

    def hasAnyChildren(self):
        return self.leftChild or self.rightChild

    def hasBothChildren(self):
        return self.leftChild and self.rightChild

st = SplayTree()
st[32] = "Cat"
st[55] = "Dog"
st[10] = "Lion"
st[41] = "Zebra"
st[19] = "Fox"
st[1] = "Wolf"
st[16] = "Tiger"
st[12] = "Pig"
st.inorder()
```

I think my moveUp() method is where things are going wrong.But I can't seem to figure out what exactly is going wrong?

Comment: I think your rotation methods are slightly buggy. The line `rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild` in the first `if` in `rotateLeft` (and the equivalent line in `rotateRight`) should be run unconditionally. Otherwise you can have a left over connection from the `rotRoot` to the `newRoot` that should have been replaced by `None`.

Comment: @Blckknght That's a excellent observation.Now the code is running but giving incorrect result.The last node added is not going to the root!I rechecked the moveUp() code and don't seem to find anything suspicious.

Comment: @Blckknght Oh now its working fine...just made some slight adjustments.Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were two issues in your code.

The first was that you had a subtle bug in your rotation methods, where you were sometimes failing to set one of the child links to `None` when you should. The line `rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild` in the first `if` in `rotateLeft` (and the equivalent line in `rotateRight`) should be run unconditionally. Just move it up out of the `if` to fix it.

The second issue is that you're calling `moveUp` too often. You're running it from every recursive call to `_put`, but since it `moveUp` calls itself recursively too, that means it runs too often. Indent the calls in `_put` so that they're part of the `else` blocks where you're creating the new nodes. That way, you will only call `moveUp` from the last `_put` call, rather than from all of them.

```
def _put(self,key,val,currentNode):               
     if key < currentNode.key:
        if currentNode.hasLeftChild():
            self._put(key,val,currentNode.leftChild)
        else:
            currentNode.leftChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
            self.moveUp(currentNode.leftChild)                     # increase indent here!

     else:
        if currentNode.hasRightChild():
            self._put(key,val,currentNode.rightChild)
        else:
            currentNode.rightChild = TreeNode(key,val,parent=currentNode)
            self.moveUp(currentNode.rightChild)                    # here too

def rotateLeft(self, rotRoot):
    newRoot = rotRoot.rightChild
    rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild       # move this line up, out of the if
    if newRoot.leftChild is not None:
        newRoot.leftChild.parent = rotRoot
    newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
    if rotRoot.parent is None:
        self.root = newRoot
    # make connection between parent and node
    else:
        if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
            rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
        else:
            rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
    newRoot.leftChild = rotRoot
    rotRoot.parent = newRoot

def rotateRight(self, rotRoot):
    newRoot = rotRoot.leftChild
    rotRoot.leftChild = newRoot.rightChild       # this one as well
    if newRoot.rightChild is not None:
        newRoot.rightChild.parent = rotRoot
    newRoot.parent = rotRoot.parent
    if rotRoot.parent is None:
        self.root = newRoot
    else:
        if rotRoot.isLeftChild():
            rotRoot.parent.leftChild = newRoot
        else:
            rotRoot.parent.rightChild = newRoot
    newRoot.rightChild = rotRoot
    rotRoot.parent = newRoot
```

Comment: Yep did as you said especially the unconditional call to
    rotRoot.rightChild = newRoot.leftChild and same for the other one
and this seems to fix the problem completely.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your moveUp in two places:

```
if currentNode.isRightChild() and currentNode.parent.isLeftChild():
    self.rotateLeft(currentNode.parent)
    self.rotateRight(currentNode.parent.parent) // Here
elif currentNode.isLeftChild() and currentNode.parent.isRightChild():
    self.rotateRight(currentNode.parent)
    self.rotateLeft(currentNode.parent.parent) // Here
```

That should help

Comment: This is incorrect. After one rotation, the `currentNode` has replaced its original `parent` in the tree, so the original grandparent is now the direct parent. The code in the question got this right.